# Update Linux Kernel is safe?

Tags: kernel, updates

I would like to know (It seems a dumb question, but I don't know the complexity about the question), is it safe to update the Linux Kernel, or will it damage the OS?

[image: LINUX KERNEL MUST BE UPDATED OR NOT?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you install official kernels released by Canonical, everything is ok and you should do all those updates because they concern your system's security mainly.  The fact that the old kernel is not removed, gives you the opportunity to reboot and use it in case something doesn't work as it should with the updated one.

One thing you should not do, is to use mainstream kernels with Ubuntu.  They are not fine tuned for the OS and they lack all the drivers released by Canonical and are contained in the **linux-image-extra** package.